# Add information from two tables to second table

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-join

I'm a newbie in query building.

I created two tables:

product:

```
productid | name | price
```

order:

```
id | productid | quantity | fullprice
```

Can I automatically calculate fullprice (product.price * order.quantity), when I add new record values (productid, quantity)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join:

```
select p.*, o.quantity, o.quantity * p.price as fullprice
from products p
inner join orders o on o.productid = p.productid
```

I would not recommend storing `fullprice`. This is derived information, that can be computed on the fly when needed, using above query. If you are going to use the query often, you might want to create a view:

```
create view v_product_orders as
select p.*, o.quantity, o.quantity * p.price as fullprice
from products p
inner join orders o on o.productid = p.productid
```

If you want to store the `fullprice`, then you need to create an insert trigger, which makes your schema more complex.